# Join to an in-memory list efficiently

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq, entity-framework

In EF, if I have a list of primatives (List), "joining" that against a table is easy:

```
var ids = int[]{1,4,6}; //some random values
var rows = context.SomeTable.Where(r => ids.Contains(r.id))
```

This gets much more complicated the instant you want to join on multiple columns:

```
var keys = something.Select(s => new { s.Field1, s.Field2 })
var rows = context.SomeTable.Where(r => keys.Contains(r => new { s.Field1, s.Field2 })); // this won't work
```

I've found two ways to join it, but neither is great:

1. Suck in the entire table, and filtering it based on the other data.  (this gets slow if the table is really large)
2. For each key, query the table (this gets slow if you have a decent number of rows to pull in)

Sometimes, the compromise I've been able to make is a modified #1: pulling in subset of the table based on a fairly unique key

```
var keys = something.Select(s => s.Field1)
var rows = context.SomeTable.Where(r => keys.Contains(s.Field1)).ToList();
foreach (var sRow in something)
{
    var joinResult = rows.Where(r => r.Field1 == sRow.Field1 && r.Field2 == sRow.Field2);
    //do stuff
}
```

But even this could pull back too much data.

I know there are ways to coax table valued parameters into ADO.Net, and ways I can build a series of .Where() clauses that are OR'd together.  Does anyone have any magic bullets?

Comment: For performance, use `context.ExecuteQuery()` to send a tailored SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a .Contains(), how about you use an inner join and "filter" that way:

```
from s in context.SomeTable
join k in keys on new {k.Field1, k.Field2} equals new {s.Field1, s.Field2}
```

There may be a typo in the above, but you get the idea...

Comment: Unless I am misremembering, this used to generate "SELECT ... FROM SomeTable" without a where clause.  Which was terrible when I had 10+ million rows in that table.

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same problem, and the solutions I came up with were:

- Naive: do a separate query for each local record
- Smarter: Create 2 lists of unique Filed1 values and unique Fiels2 values, query using 2 contains expressions and then you will have to double filter result as they might be not that accurate.

Looks like this:

```
 var unique1 = something.Select(x => x.Field1).Distinct().ToList();
 var unique2 = something.Select(x => x.Field2).Distinct().ToList();
 var priceData = rows.Where(x => unique1.Contains(x.Field1) && unique2.Contains(x.Field2));
```

- Next one is my own solution which I called BulkSelect, the idea behind it is like this:

  - Create temp table using direct SQL command
  - Upload data for SELECT command to that temp table
  - Intercept and modify SQL which was generated by EF.

I did it for Postgres, but this may be ported to MSSQL is needed. This nicely described [here](http://tsherlock.tech/2017/11/01/bulk-select-operation-using-npgsql/) and the source code is [here](https://github.com/neisbut/Npgsql.Bulk)

Comment: The first method will return "rows" values that are not present in "something"

Answer (score 0):

You can try flattening your keys and then using the same `Contains` pattern. This will probably not perform great on large queries, although you could use function indexes to store the flattened key in the database...

I have table Test with columns `K1 int, K2 int, Name varchar(50)`

```
var l = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
l.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1));
l.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2));
var s = l.Select(k => k.Item1.ToString() + "," + k.Item2.ToString());
var q = Tests.Where(t => s.Contains(t.K1.ToString() + "," + t.K2.ToString()));
foreach (var y in q) {
    Console.WriteLine(y.Name);
}
```

I've tested this in LinqPad with Linq to SQL

**First attempt that didn't work:**

I think the way to write it as a single query is something like this

```
var keys = something.Select(s => new { s.Field1, s.Field2 })
var rows = context.SomeTable.Where(r => keys.Any(k => r.Field1 == k.Field1 && r.Field2 == k.Field2));
```

Unfortunately I don't have EF on this laptop and can't even test if this is syntactically correct.

I've also no idea how performant it is if it works at all...

Comment: I don't think it will work because `keys` is a collection of objects (anonymous in this example), not of primitive types (int, string, Guid, DateTime, etc.). It will most likely throw the infamous *"Unable to create a constant value of type xyz. Only primitive types are supported..."* exception.

Comment: @Slauma Just run through a simpler example in Linqpad, and I'm pretty sure you're right.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = 
from key in keys
join thingy in context.SomeTable
on 1 = 1
where thingy.Field1 == key && thingy.Field2 == key
select thingy
```

should work, and generate reasonable SQL

Comment: I didn't try "on 1 = 1", but I would assume that it would load the entire SomeTable at that point

Comment: The query generator takes the entire query in to account, including the where clause, and will only go to the datastore when it has to (i.e. when the result is enumerated), which may be even later, after a bunch of other query expressions. I'd say give it a whirl, see where it brings you. If the resulting SQL is horrible, you can always decide against it.

Comment: It's not a good practice to set the in memory data on the left side of the JOIN. You should invert the order and always place the DbSet data on the left side and in memory data on the right. See [this](https://theworkingdad.it/2018/10/03/entity-framework-joining-in-memory-data-with-dbset/)